# What is the best way to implement a SQL(database) Listener?

Tags: sql, database, ws-eventing

What is the best way to implement a generic database which monitor a table and trigger an event(ws-event) when the table get updated. Is there any standard way to do this?

Comment: A standard way to do this would be to use some kind of message queue mechanism. Most databases have somekind of message queue built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for a database table trigger:

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i

Comment: Thank you soo much for your reference.. Do you have a sample where it send messages to a JMS Que (ie mysql event trigger) when an insertion happen

Comment: Sorry, I have never used JMS myself.